# C#: Declare preprocessor symbol for all configurations

Tags: c#

I need to declare a preprocessor symbol for my C# project, which always needs to be declared, no matter the configuration (Debug, Release, ...).

Is there a way to do so, so that if a new configuration is created, I won't need to add the symbol manually?

FYI, I need this as I'm using shared files between projects (I don't want my projects to depend on each other or on a shared assembly).

Answer (score 4):

you can define a preprocessor symbol during the build by using /define
MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0feaad6z.aspx

You can also define preprocessor symbols using the build configuration dialog of a projects settings. Image below:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/22128199/Build.png

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know if I can use it as I'm always building things within VS2010, at least locally.

Comment: Thats exactly what its for, you set it in the build options on the project. If you goto the properties for a given project select the build tab (2010 or 2011, dont have 2008 installed on this machine) and there you can set the build options. In 2010 and 2011 you can just set compilation symbols directly (semi-colon seperated) as it is its own option on the build tab 'Conditional compilation symbols'.

Comment: added a link to show the build dialog i am referring to in my answer. Hope this helps.

Comment: I know I can add it in "Conditional compilation symbols" in the "build" tab, but I have to do it for each and every configuration, and I need to manually add it to any new configuration that might be created later on. I noticed the "All configurations", but it only works for existing configurations, and it removes any specific symbol a configuration might have had before. I would like to define my symbol once and for all somewhere, and that it would be defined for all current and future configurations...but I don't know whether it's possible...

Comment: This post seems to reference what you are looking for, basically there is no easy way to have a solution wide, config agnostic symbol. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpide/thread/92e4e8c8-4614-4e78-a0f8-86649f606b23

Comment: Actually I'm not trying to set it for a whole solution, just one project. Basically I would want to be able to add <DefineConstants>SYMBOL</DefineConstants> once in my csproj and that SYMBOL be used everywhere, for all current and future configurations. I tried adding it to the 1st <PropertyGroup> but it doesn't do anything...